# SocketTasksExtensions result of ConnectAsync

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

Can someone help me understand how the ConnectAsync in the [SocketTasksExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.sockettaskextensions.connectasync?view=netcore-3.0) works?

How do I know if the connect request was successful? If the task completes does this mean it was successful? Or do I need to check the [Socket.Connected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connected?view=netcore-3.0) property? And if so, how do I get the error messages when connecting? Are they thrown as exceptions in the ConnectAsync method?

I couldn't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Like all async methods, you use `await` to await for it to complete asynchronously and check the result. If there are any exceptions, they'll be propagated by `await`. This is *very well documented* since its a fundamental concept for all .NET code since 2012. What did you try? What does your code look like?

Comment: Check for example [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: That said, the [Asynchronous Client Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/using-an-asynchronous-client-socket?view=netcore-3.0) docs use the pre-Task API. In the task-based API, `Begin/End` methods are replaced with a single `await`, eg `await socket.SendAsync()`. The async extensions appeared in .NET Old 4.7.1 and the docs weren't updated.